# Floppy disk adapter

Tags: floppy-disk

I intend to make a circuit which controls a floppy disk drive. I am using the [WD35C65B](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/westernDigital/_dataBooks/1991_SystemLogic_Imaging_Storage/31_WD37C65C.pdf) chip as controller and a PIC32MX250F256 as microcontroller. I have already figured out most of the stuff. My questions which remain are:

- What is the function of the pins LDOR, LDCR, and DCHGEN ?
- Can I add an USB to SATA converter?

The circuit outputs USB signals.I know that utilizing a FDD with SATA makes no sense per se. Just for the sake of it, would it be possible? Which USB-to-SATA converter can I use? I know the crystal for the PIC32 is missing. Plan:[image]

Comment: Site rules: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: Did you read the datasheet description how the chip works and how do control and operation registers affect it? The register contents are also described in the datasheet. What specifically is unclear, in order not to replicate the description in the datasheet here?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you seem to lack experience on finding /reading the datasheet?  https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/128746/NEC/WD37C65C.html

[image]

Can you add a USB Adapter to  the parallel port?  Yes if you know how.

Comment: I know where to find the datasheet. What I don´t understand is what the control/operations register does exactly do. The microcontroller will output the parallel data onto the USB pins (D+/-).

Comment: @Count_Omega Page 31-10 describes the Control Register. Page 31-19 describes the Operations Register. I know this because I looked at the table of contents.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. As I understand it the operations register is used to select disk drives and enable motors, right? And the control register is used for data transfer rate.

Comment: To get back to my original question, can I use an USB 2.0 to SATA bridge IC in order to get a SATA device like a HDD?

Comment: That's what they are for yes. But what are the driving factor that make  you want to design an obsolete device. I have a couple of these boards in my junk bin. Maybe worth  $15 on Amazon

Answer (score 0):

LDOR and LDCR are used for writing to Operations Register and Control Register, respectively.

DCHGEN enables reading disk change status.

No you can't add USB to SATA converter to make this connect to a PC as SATA floppy drive device. These converters are used to connect SATA devices to USB host, not the other way around.